# What is this icon name?

Tags: flutter, icons

I want to use this icon on my Flutter app, unfortunately I do not know the name. Someone could tell me what's the name?

[image]

Comment: Its a "more" icon in a rounded square ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the three points icon is:

```
Icon(Icons.more_horiz)
```

and you can reach the same shape over it like this:

```
Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  border: Border.all(
   color: Colors.black,
   width: 1, 
  ),
 ),
 child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
 ),
```

this will result in something like this, I didn't compare them, so changing just the padding and border, and border radius values will get you there

Comment: Thank you veery much